# Angular mat-sidenav not displaying on safari (comp or mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have created a side nav using Angular material and it is only displaying on chrome and not on safari. I have looked everywhere for a solution and can not seem to find one! This is my html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" [fixedInViewport]="true"  [attr.role]="(screenWidth<769) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
               [mode]="(screenWidth<769) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!(screenWidth<769)">
    <mat-toolbar class="logo-toolbar">
      <div class="navbar-logo">
        <img class="logo" src="assets/img/icons/logo-white.png">
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <div class="lateral-navbar-item" *ngFor="let item of navbarList" [ngClass]="{'active': router.url.includes(item.routerLink)}"
           [routerLink]="item.routerLink">
        <img height="32" width="32" [src]="router.url.includes(item.routerLink) ? item.activeImgUrl : item.imgUrl">
        <span>{{item.content}}</span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="screenWidth < 769" class="lateral-navbar-item logoutButton" (click)="logout()">
        <img height="32" width="32" src="../assets/svg/lateral-navbar-icons/log-out.svg">
        <span>Logout</span>
      </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar *ngIf="screenWidth < 769" class="collapsedSideNav">
      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="screenWidth<769">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Has anyone had this issue/has anyone managed to solve this issue?

**EDIT - I should add that the items are there just not visible. If i manage to find them and click them they do route me to the correct page!**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and could resolve using below. (Angular Mat - 5)

```
.mat-drawer-container{
      position: unset!important;
 }
```

Comment: This works also for mat-sidenav-container. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a bit different (but similar) problem with "position: unset !important;" for ".mat-drawer-container" this is my template:

```
<mat-toolbar class="header top-panel">
// content...
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" class="sidenav">
    // content...
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
    // content...
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-toolbar class="footer">
// content...
</mat-toolbar>
```

Angular 9. And the problem. mat-tooltip not visible only in the chrome+iPhone loading vertical layout. And only if open link from bookmarks or reloading after it was opened from chrome bookmarked links.

- Close+Open chrome on iOS 13 and site reloads well.
- write domain name and site (app) reloads well
- Same iOS/device but Safari - all okay
- Mac book pro all browsers (Safari, Chrome, Yandex) and all okay
- Different devices emulators in the chrome (from mac book) - all okay
- Change vertical layout to landscape gives mat-tooltip back and it remains with us

So. Unset of mat-drawer-container position resolved the problem but triggered others with auto-layout of other elements.

Resuming. Problem was only iOS 13 + iPhone + Chrome. As you know no debug instruments for chrome (iOS). Can't test it out!

In nutshell. Partially resolved. But I am looking for a more deep solution. Maybe smdy found - share here pls.

[image: The bug screenshot]

The bag still exists with "position: unset !important;" but now not so critical. Menu in toolbar available after a light swap.